# jquery button click event not invoking

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a button group in from wizard ...save and cancel button show when wizard reached at final step. this code in separate js code file that is use multiple time.

here is the js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//for form wizard
// Step show event
$("#smartwizard").on("showStep", function (e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection, stepPosition) {
    //alert("You are on step "+stepNumber+" now");
    if (stepPosition === 'first') {
        $("#savecancle").hide();
        $("#prev-btn").addClass('disabled');
    } else if (stepPosition === 'final') {
        $("#savecancle").show().css("float", "right");
        $("#next-btn").addClass('disabled');
    } else {
        $("#prev-btn").removeClass('disabled');
        $("#next-btn").removeClass('disabled');
    }
});

// Toolbar extra buttons
var btnFinish = $('<button></button>').text('Save')
                                 .addClass('btn btn-info').attr("id","save")
                                 .on('click', function () { /*alert('Finish Clicked');*/ });
var btnCancel = $('<button></button>').text('Cancel')
                                 .addClass('btn btn-danger')
                                 .on('click', function () { $('#smartwizard').smartWizard("reset"); });

// Smart Wizard 1
$('#smartwizard').smartWizard({
    selected: 0,
    theme: 'arrows',
    transitionEffect: 'fade',
    showStepURLhash: false,
    toolbarSettings: {
        toolbarPosition: 'bottom',
        toolbarExtraButtons: [btnFinish, btnCancel]
    }
});
```

});

when i click on save button the event dose not fired.
here is my click button code in .cshtml file

```
$("#save").click(function () {
                    var isAllValid = true;
                    //Save if valid
                    if (isAllValid) {
                        var data = {
                            tblOrderDetailSubs: orderItems
                        }

                        $(this).val('Please wait...');

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Order/OrderAdd',
                            type: "POST",
                            data: data,
                            success: function (d) {
                                if (d.status == true) {
                                    alert('Successfully done.');
                                    //clear form
                                    orderItems = [];
                                }
                                else {
                                    alert('Failed');
                                }
                                $('#save').val('Save');
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert('Error. Please try again.');
                                $('#save').val('Save');
                            }
                        });
                    }

                });
```

can anyone help me ..?
thanks in advance.

Comment: In your cshtml file, right in the line before defining your click function, do this: `console.log($("#save"));`

Comment: no actually both are in different file.

Comment: Whatever, add that line, run the page and check the console.

Comment: ok give me this out put...

SAVE Value 
init [button#save.btn.btn-sm.btn-success, context: document, selector: "#save"]
0: button#save.btn.btn-sm.btn-success
context: document
length: 1
selector: "#save"
__proto__: Object(0)

Comment: this give me on 1st step of wizard...

Comment: because in last step when click on save button my method is not executed

Comment: Do a `console.log('click handler called');` inside your click handler, as the first line of code of the click handler function.

Comment: i cant understand. can u give me an example plz

Comment: what i have to exactly do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button might not be in the document yet at the moment you execute:

```
$("#save").click(function () {
    ...
});
```

Use event delegation to be sure that the event is captured once the button is available:

```
$("#smartwizard").on("click", "#save", function () {
    ...
});
```